# Execute a Groovy class in a package from the command line

Tags: command-line, groovy, package

Is there a way to execute a Groovy class by specifying the package with dots, as with java?

Example: File ./my/package/MyClass.groovy:

```
package my.package

class MyClass {
  static void main(String[] args) {
    println "ok"
  }
}
```

```
> cd my/package
my/package> groovy MyClass
ok
> cd ../..
> groovy my/package/MyClass.groovy
ok
> groovy my/package/MyClass
ok
> groovy my.package.MyClass
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: my.package.MyClass
```

I was expecting the last command to work. I tried various ways of setting the classpath, to no avail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, *package* is a reserved keyword, so you can't use it as a a package name.

Second of all, you can't do that in Groovy, since the dot notation is used for classes, not for scripts, so you need a compiled class file to use it.

Still, you can replace the groovy command with java + classpath:

`java -cp /usr/share/java/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-1.6.3.jar:. my.some.MyClass`

You can add an alias to it 'g_java' for instance to make it less verbose.

Comment: It sounds like the right answer, but it isn't working. I used "my.package" as an example, by the way- a bad one I realize. Anyway, even with an acceptable package name, and after compilation with groovyc, it doesn't work.

    groovyc my/some/MyClass.groovy
    export CLASSPATH=.
    ls my/some/MyClass.class
    my/some/MyClass.class

    groovy my.some.MyClass
    Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/olivier/my.some.MyClass (/Users/olivier/my.some.MyClass)

?

Comment: You're right, I don't know how I missed that. If you don't mind cheating a bit, you can replace the groovy command with java + classpath:

java -cp /usr/share/java/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-1.6.3.jar:. my.some.MyClass

You can add an alias to it 'g_java' for instance to make it less verbose.

Comment: Thanks. It works. So, the answer to my original question is: No, it doesn't work this way in Groovy. You have to use javac and java.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this answer. +1. Is there an extra period at the end of your java... line?